# Individual cell balancing on multiple packs

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, batteries, bms, battery-balance

UPDATED: I edited my question to clarify

I'm building a 4s4p pack with 18650's. What is the best method to achieve on a per-cell balancing & protection if that makes sense? Most of the 4s BMS I looked at cannot achieve this, I concluded this by looking at the wiring diagram of most of them, example below shows the BMS working on each individual cell however this would only work on a 4s1p not a 4s4p.

[image]

The only other method I thought about is to forget about the 4s4p and instead go for 16s1p, with that arrangement the BMS tends to be on per cell basis if I'm not mistaken?

My only objective here is to ensure each individual cell is protected and well balanced, I don't know if I'm being over cautious here. The cells I am using are brand new Samsung 35E.

Comment: _"all of the 4s BMS I looked at cannot achieve this."_ - which ones did you look at, and how do you know they can't do it?

Comment: Hi Bruce, perhaps an incorrect wording on my part, I looked at a handful of ones by searching their wiring diagrams on google, see the example below, I don't see how that can work on multiple packs as most of the 4s balance has 1 wire per cell

https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.aliexpress.com%2Fi%2F32909172908.html&psig=AOvVaw2YhX989BTmBvuFg5KQlnRS&ust=1595285372740000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCJjQ96Gz2uoCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAp

Comment: What lead you to the conclusion that the BMS will work with 4S1P but not 4S4P?

Comment: it will work but it wont achieve the level of control I'm after that is on a cell by cell basis, when using a bms on a 4s1p each cell is balances individually, when using 4s4p that isn't the case as the cells in parallel are treated as one as also mentioned in the answer below

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities for how balancing is done depending on the pack architecture.  If the pack is 4 series, each one composed of 4 parallel cells, then no balancing is required for the cells in parallel.  They are directly connected together and cannot get out of balance.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4dtUK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you have 4 strings of 4 cells, each string is 4 cells in series and the 4 strings are in parallel, then you need a balance controller for each of the strings.  This pack architecture has no real advantage over the standard 4s4p unless the strings can be isolated (you get some tolerance for cell failures in this case).  With this architecture you have to be very careful about balancing.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffPl2Z.png)</sup>

Comment: Hi Dean, Thank you for your response, with the first option you mention about not needing to balance cells in parallel - is there any disadvantage to this when building much larger packs like a 12s12p ?

Comment: A failure of one of the cells in a parallel group can cause pack failure.  I would think that if you are using multiple parallel cells in a pack, the charger must be designed to never expose any of the cell groups to more then 4.2V (or whatever the cell termination voltage is), rather than charging the pack to 4.2V * series count and then balancing the cells (which some cheap chargers do)